# Theoretical network protocol with ports higher than 65535

Tags: networking, network-protocols, iana

to settle an argument at work.
Is it possible, in theory, to create a network protocol with ports higher than 65535 and get it approved by [IANA](http://www.iana.org/) ?

if not, why not ?

Comment: This question seems to be more about the rules and regulations of IANA than anything programming related.

Comment: Actually, as a programmer in the area of networks, it became very relevant to know if ports have a theoretical (at least regulatory) bound. maybe my wording could be better (suggestions for edits are welcome) but I still believe the question is valid and on topic.

Comment: What IANA would/wouldn't sign off on is a purely political thing. If you're defining your own protocol you can theoretically put any size integer you wanted as the port numbers, only politics stands in the way.

Comment: that piece of information, the one you just gave in your comment, is the one I did not know, and needed to know in order to handle ports properly in my program. and the reason I posted this question here. so, thanks for your answer. it helps. @Flexo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to create one with an arbitrary number of ports.

Getting it approved by IANA (and IETF, ISO and whoever else are concerned) is just a matter of getting enough people to use your wonderful new invention. Which is extremely unlikely but not theoretically impossible.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using TCP or UDP on top of IP, then no. Both TCP and UDP only use 16 bits for the port number. If you are using some other protocol suite such as IPX/SPX, then it depends on that protocol. If you are making your own protocol, then you can do whatever you want. Getting it approved by IANA is a different story.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

2^16 = 65536 different ports

Since computer numbers start counting at 0, this leaves 65535 as the max.